# Integrating Ads in a Game

Tags: android, view, panel, mobclix

i have a 2D game which has my custom ViewPanel which handles all the drawings (i don't have android Button elements, all my game controls are painted/handled internally).

this is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my activity's onCreate() main code:

```
    viewPanel = new ViewPanel(this);
    setContentView(viewPanel);
```

**from this point my ViewPanel handles all the drawings/events.**

Now, 
i want to integrate Ads (Mobclix), and this is how i do it:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.mobclix_advertising_view);
    Mobclix.onCreate(this);

    adview_banner = (MobclixMMABannerXLAdView) findViewById(R.id.advertising_banner_view);
    adview_banner.addMobclixAdViewListener(this);
    adview_banner.setRefreshTime(30000);
    adview_banner.getAd();
```

HOWEVER! it seems i can either setContentView on my **ViewPanel** OR on **"advertising_banner_view"** not both. So basically either i see my game drawing OR the advertising bar.

How can i see them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

my_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Now just use my_layout as you main layout, and call addView twice on it, once with your ViewPanel and once with your AdView. You can set the gravity of the adview to float it where ever you want on the screen.

Comment: I get this error:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.myGame.ViewPanel

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you'd declared your ViewPanel as an actual compound controll. I've modified my answer.

Comment: Sorry for a noob question, but what do you mean by "assign your view panel to the LinearLayout"?

Comment: Sorry, I was actually mistaken in my response. Please see my update.

Comment: When i do this:
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.game); 
The mainLayout gets null. Why?

Comment: OK it works now! However, my ViewPanel has lost its onTouchEvent capabilities.

Comment: Good to hear Alex! I hope you can get your onTouchEvents working again. If you found my answer helpful, would you mind accepting it by clicking on the checkmark next to my response? P.S. If you can't get your onTouchEvents working, you can always ask another question here on SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
game.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.package.ViewPanel />
<com.package.MobclixMMABannerXLAdView />
</LinearLayout>
```

in your code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

than you can use findviewbyid to get those views.

Comment: Also, I get this error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.myGame.ViewPanel